# Does this cause a MongoDB performance issue (when doing the `limit` on the client-side by 'breaking' the `cursor`)?

Tags: performance, mongodb

Though this has nothing to do with PHP specifically, I use PHP in the following examples.

Let's say this is the 'normal' way of limiting results.

```
$db->users->find()->limit(10);
```

This is probably the fastest way, but there are some restrictions here... In the following example, I'll filter out all rows that have the save value for a certain column as the previous row:

```
$cursor = $db->users->find();
$prev = null;
$results = array();
foreach ($cursor as $row) {
    if ($row['coll'] != $prev['coll']) {
        $results[] = $row;
        $prev = $row;
    }
}
```

But you still want to limit the results to 10, of course. So you could use the following:

```
$cursor = $db->users->find();
$prev = null;
$results = array();
foreach ($cursor as $row) {
    if ($row['coll'] != $prev['coll']) {
        $results[] = $row;
        if (count($results) == 10) break;
        $prev = $row;
    }
}
```

Explanation: since the `$cursor` does not actually load the results from the database, `break`ing the `foreach`-loop will `limit` it just as the `limit(...)`-function does.

Just for sure, is this really working as I'm saying, or are there any performance issues I'm not aware of?

Thank you very much,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Explanation: since the $cursor does not actually load the results from the database, breaking the foreach-loop will limit it just as the limit(...)-function does.

This is not 100% true.

When you do the `foreach`, you're basically issuing a series of [`hasNext`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.hasnext.php) / [`getNext`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.getnext.php) that is looping through the data.

However, underneath this layer, the driver is actually requesting and receiving batches of results. When you do a `getNext` the driver will seamlessly fetch the next batch for you.

You can control the batch size. The details in the documentation should help [clarify what's happening](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.batchsize.php).

In your second example, if you get to 10 and then `break` there are two side effects:

1. The cursor remains open on the server (times out in 10 minutes, generally not a big impact).
2. You may have more data cached in `$cursor`. This cache will go away when `$cursor` goes out of scope.

In most cases, these side effects are "not a big deal". But if you're doing lots of this processing in a single process, you'll want to "clean up" to avoid having cursors hanging around.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! Do you know how I can close the `$cursor` in PHP. For example, is just `unset`-ing it enough?

Comment: `unset()` or just having it go out of scope (*leaving the function where it is initialized*)